# Autocomplete for text area using entered values

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to do autocomplete for textarea using entered values from browser. It is working for Textbox but not working Text area.

Comment: share your code. Do you want to fetch data from database or predefined values ?

Comment: use flexselect autocomplete jquery

Comment: <textarea id="txtMealDesc" name="txtMealDesc"  cols="10" rows="3" autocomplete="on" style="text-transform: uppercase"></textarea>                Not from DB using browser entered history. Like we will get for textbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normal textbox indeed get autocomplete behaviour for free.

As far as i know, you can get similar behaviour for textarea (even better, with all history) with installing [lazarus](http://getlazarus.com/download) plugin in your web browser.

Once installed, you will get a small cross icon on the top right corner. Clicking it will popup previous entries.

I usually don't like to install third party plugin in my web browser but this can save a lot of time and frustration when accidentally loosing all the text we already type.

Comment: Ya this one required. I dont want to store any values. Thanks i will try this.

Answer (score 0):

You Need to use external plugin

**Scripts and CSS**

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css"/> 
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

**HTML**

```
<textarea id="demo"></textarea>
```

**Script**

```
<script>
$(function() {
//Get the Data from a JSON or Hidden Feild
var availableTags = ["jQuery.com", "jQueryUI.com", "jQueryMobile.com",     "jQueryScript.net", "jQuery", "Free jQuery Plugins"]; // array of autocomplete words
var minWordLength = 2;
function split(val) {
return val.split(' ');
}

function extractLast(term) {
return split(term).pop();
}
$("#demo") // jQuery Selector
// don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
.bind("keydown", function(event) {
if (event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB && $(this).data("ui-autocomplete").menu.active)        {
event.preventDefault();
}
}).autocomplete({
minLength: minWordLength,
source: function(request, response) {
// delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
var term = extractLast(request.term);
if(term.length >= minWordLength){
response($.ui.autocomplete.filter( availableTags, term ));
}
},
focus: function() {
// prevent value inserted on focus
return false;
},
select: function(event, ui) {
var terms = split(this.value);
// remove the current input
terms.pop();
// add the selected item
terms.push(ui.item.value);
// add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
terms.push("");
this.value = terms.join(" ");
return false;
}
});
});
</script>
```

[**DEMO LINK**](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Simple-jQuery-jQuery-UI-Autocomplete-Plugin-For-Textareas/)

[**ANOTHER PLUGIN TEXTEXTJS**](http://textextjs.com/manual/examples/autocomplete-with-custom-render.html)

Comment: But you are storing data in array. i want to take those values from browser like previously submitted value.

Comment: @PrashantGRathod the you have not provided any code secondly he can get data in json format or from hidden field

Comment: <input type="text" id="txtPaxName" name="txtPaxName" autocomplete="on" /> this is simple textbox if i make autocomplete then secound time i enter previously entered first charecter then it will display previously entered value. Like this I want for TEXTAREA. Because we dont have property like multiline for textbox

Comment: @PrashantGRathod this is what i've provided did you checked it?

Comment: I tried your code its working for stored array value. How can i store user entered value in array?

Comment: means the values that user type but doesnot store?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to include **jquery UI** then use the example code

**HTML**

```
<div class="ui-widget">
<label for="tags">Tags:</label>
<textarea id="tags" size="30"></textarea>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(function () {
$("document").ready(function () {
    var availableTags = [
        "ActionScript",
        "AppleScript",
        "Asp",
        "BASIC",
        "C",
        "C++",
        "Clojure",
        "COBOL",
        "ColdFusion",
        "Erlang",
        "Fortran",
        "Groovy",
        "Haskell",
        "Java",
        "JavaScript",
        "Lisp",
        "Perl",
        "PHP",
        "Python",
        "Ruby",
        "Scala",
        "Scheme"];

    $("#tags").on("keydown", function () {
        var newY = $(this).textareaHelper('caretPos').top + (parseInt($(this).css('font-size'), 10) * 1.5);
        var newX = $(this).textareaHelper('caretPos').left;
        var posString = "left+" + newX + "px top+" + newY + "px";
        $(this).autocomplete("option", "position", {
            my: "left top",
            at: posString
        });
    });

    $("#tags ").autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
    });
});

});
```

Comment: check what parshant is asking, I provided the same solution using plugin but he is unable to understand it

Comment: Hi Arijit/Vinod, I got your post but i dont want to store autocomplete values. As both of your code you storing values in array and retrieving. But in my condition i want user entered values not stored values. Please suggest me.

Comment: @PrashantGRathod You can only show stored values as autocomplete. Please post the working code for textbox as you expected.

Comment: <input type="text" style="text-transform: uppercase" id="txtPaxName" name="txtPaxName" value="" autocomplete="on" />                                      This simple code. So how can i store user entered value in array?

Answer (score 0):

Browsers do not currently support autocompletion for a textarea. The [`autocomplete`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-fe-autocomplete) attribute is formally allowed for `textarea` in HTML5 and it has the default value of `on`, but this value just means that browsers are *allowed* to use autocompletion. They do not actually use it for textareas, apparently because it would seldom be useful and could actually be confusing. It is much more probably that a user wants to reuse his address information, entered in single-line text input fields, than some longish text he has entered in, say, a feedback form of some site and now some other site happens to have a comments textarea with the same name.

Thus, all you can do is to set up some autocomplete functionality of your own. (This is what other answers suggest in various ways.) This means that you need to store user input somehow (which is what browsers do for their own autocompletion operations too), e.g. in cookies or in `localStorage`. This generally means that the functionality works inside a site, on pages using the same technique to implement it, but not across sites.